# Vertical Layout Group Auto Expansion

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

I am running into a problem with layout groups in Unity that I do not understand and was hoping for some insight.

My goal is to create a 12 button keypad contained in the bottom half of the screen of a mobile device that would look something like this:

123

456

789

-0-

My approach to this was to use a vertical layout group to first split the screen into a top half and bottom half and then use another vertical layout group on the bottom half to make 4 rows. Each row would have a horizontal layout group with 3 buttons. The problem I am running into is that when I add the 4 rows into the bottom layout group (bottom half of the screen) it starts to automatically expand and ends up taking up much more than just the bottom half of the screen. In the end I just want the 12 buttons contained in the bottom half of the screen and I keep toggling and playing with child control and force expand but do not understand why the automatic resizing is happening. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you, and wishing you a great day

Answer (score 0):

Just use grid layout group that would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use grid layout and make the fixed column count and get the center layout, and use this github https://github.com/mrbeardy/BeardyGridLayout, I get it from unity forum

Hope you like it :)